# creating a child and parent process

Tags: c, linux, sockets, process, parent-child

```
int main()
{
    pid_t cpid, w;
    int status;

    CreateSocket();   // it recievs data from the client

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {            /* Code executed by child */
        CHECKTASKS();            //timer created for calling the task for every 2ms,10
    } else {
        do {
            w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
            if (w == -1) {
                perror("waitpid");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
            } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
            } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
                printf("continued\n");
            }
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

I created a child process and I am calling a  CreateSocket();   // it recievs data from the client via the ip address and port number. I am calling this before creating a child process. If i do like that- will it be a parent process ??  I am calling a another function after creating a child process i.e CHECKTASKS(); //timer created for calling the task for every 2ms,10ms and 100ms// to run in the background . Is the CHECKTASKS will be running in the background as a separate process. Is it possible if I code like above in c for linux OS ??

Comment: As is, no, this won't come close to working (as I understand your project).  Please note, [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3354789/user3354789?tab=questions&sort=newest) has asked at least 8 questions about this project, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3367968/user3367968) 3 questions, and now you with (so far) 1.  I don't know if you are one person or a group of classmates or coworkers but if you are trying to conceal your efforts you are doing a terrible job of it.  Why not follow the rules?  Layout what you want to do *in detail* and show how you approached it so far.

Comment: There are a dozen people here that I can name off the top of my head, including myself, who are capable and willing to *help* you.  But they aren't going to *do* the project for you.  The best advice I can give you is detail the grand overview of what you are trying to do, show what you have done so far, ask one *specific* question at a time and incorporate the answer into your *next* question.  Maybe I am being unfair but so far I have seen you ask the same question about 10 different ways because no *one* answer gave you complete, workable code to incorporate unchanged into your project.